# SQLite Error: Constraint Failed

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a common problem, and have looked at several solutions but haven't seen one that fits this case.

I have a temporary table that is defined as follows:

```
public static final String GROUP_TABLE_CREATE =
         "CREATE TEMP TABLE "+GROUP_TABLE_NAME+" ("
         +GROUP_ID_COLUMN_NAME+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
         +GROUP_GROUP_ID_COLUMN_NAME+" INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE, "
         +GROUP_COLUMN_NAME+" VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL)";
```

The table is created without any problems.  I then download some data to insert into it and use the following query to insert it:

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(WhereWolfOpenHelper.GROUP_GROUP_ID_COLUMN_NAME, groupID);
contentValues.put(WhereWolfOpenHelper.GROUP_COLUMN_NAME, groupName);
db.insert(WhereWolfOpenHelper.GROUP_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
```

And then I get the following error:

```
08-05 08:52:37.791: ERROR/Database(847): Error inserting group_name=Friends group_id=2
08-05 08:52:37.791: ERROR/Database(847): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
```

The error appears **twice**, and the only data in the database is the group named Friends (there should be two more entries).

I have another table with very similar code that works without any problems, so I'm guessing it's just some silly mistake that I haven't spotted.  Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: hi vicki try to remove the UNIQUE attribute of GROUP_GROUP_ID_COLUMN_NAME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "constraint failed" than something in table scheme should tell us what is wrong.
I see what it show data what it want to insert, this means what **NOT NULL** constraint is OK.
In this case I've only one assumption what you already inserted some GROUP_GROUP_ID_COLUMN_NAME with value **2** and **UNIQUE** constraint is failed because of that.

Comment: I took out the unique constraint and it revealed the source of my problem - I'd forgotten to increment an iterator and was trying to put the same row in 3 times!  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a temporary table on purpose? A temporary table dies once the DB connection is closed. If this is the case, the table will get created and the insert will not correspond to any table. So the constraint 19 can correspond to 'Table not found'

Comment: Yes I'm creating a temporary table on purpose, and it is created immediately before that data is put in it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass null values in insert method. Pass empty strings.